# Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $stateProvider <- $state

Tags: arrays, angularjs, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

Executing below unit test gives "Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $stateProvider <- $state". I have attached the angular-ui-router.min.js in karma file.

```
 describe("Unit tests", function() {

  var $rootScope, $injector, $state;
  console.log("hello");

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$state_, _$injector_, $templateCache) {
    console.log("hello1");
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    $injector = _$injector_;
    $state = _$state_;
  }));

  describe("states", function() {
    it("verify state configuration", function() {
        var config = $state.get("DRaaS");
        console.log(config, "cc");
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You haven't loaded any module, so no service at all is available. Add this before your beforeEach:

```
beforeEach(module('ui.router'));
```

Comment: This answer put me in the right direction. I forgot to add `angular-ui-router` to my files property inside karma.conf.

Comment: I am currently absolutely hating karma because of the fact that this is actually required!  Is there any way to mock/stub/fake the $stateProvider so I don't need to require 'ui-router'?  I want to be able to test my code in isolation (hence UNIT tests) and mock out all these other dependencies.

Comment: @AaronJanes yes there is. You can use something like this      $provide.service('$state', function ($q) {
                var $stateService = {
                    current: {
                        url: "/",
                        views: {},
                        name: "root.signin"
                    }
                };
                return $stateService;
            });