# Injecting mock $state into an angular unit test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, angular-ui-router

I'm a relative weakling at Angular unit testing and I'm struggling mightily to bootstrap what strikes me as a simple unit test.

My Class

```
class CampaignController {
    constructor($state) {
        this.$state = $state;
    }

    submit() {
        this.$state.transitionTo('some.state');
    }
}
export { CampaignController };
```

My Test

```
import { expect } from 'chai';
import angular from 'angular';
import { CampaignController } from './campaign.controller';

let component;

describe('campaign-controller', function() {

    var $state;

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$state_) {
        $state = _$state_;
        component = new CampaignController($state);
    }));


    it('should update state on submit', () => {
        component.submit();
        expect($state.current.name).to.be('some.state');
    });
});
```

I end up getting this error

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $stateProvider <- $state
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

You're not loading any modules in your `beforeEach`, so angular-ui router is not available.  At the very least, you need to load the ui.router module.

For example, you might have a separate beforeEach block before yours:

```
beforeEach(module('ui.router'));

beforeEach(inject(function (_$state_) {
    $state = _$state_;
    component = new CampaignController($state);
}));
```

Comment: A similar issue was reported here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28737371/error-injectorunpr-unknown-provider-stateprovider-state